# Cannot convert argument from 'this' to Node<T>*

Tags: c++

I'm working on a new project to understand templates better.
I have a problem converting an augment; I'm not sure how I can handle this problem and would like to learn about this.
It's a project on Binary Search Tree.

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>* Tree<T>::insertion(Node<T>* root , T value){
    if (this == NULL) {
        Node n = new Node(value);
        return n;
    }
    if (value < this->value)
        this->left = insert(this->left, value);
    else if (value > this->value)
        this->right = insert(this->right, value);
    return root;
}

template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::insert(T value) {
    insertion(this, value);
}
```

class Tree:

```
class Tree {
private:
    Node<T>* root;

public:
    Tree() {
        this->root = NULL;
    };
    ~Tree() { recursiveDeletion(this->root);  }
    void insert(T value);
    int find(T value) const;
    //int size() const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &b, Tree const &t);
    Node<T>* insertion(Node<T> *root, T value);

};
```

class Node:

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
private:
    Node *right, *left;
    T value;
public:
    Node() {
        right = NULL = left;
    }
    Node(T value) { 
        this->value = value;
        right = NULL = left;
    };
};
```

main:

```
void main()
{
    Tree<int> *root = new Tree<int>();
    root->insert(1);
    root->insert(2);
    root->insert(-2);
    root->insert(-1);
    root->insert(2);
    root->find(-1);
    root->size();
    cout << root << endl;
}
```

> Error C2664   'Node *Tree::insertion(Node *,T)': cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'Tree *const ' to 'Node *'

Comment: Because a `Node` is not a `Tree`?

Comment: `if (this == NULL)`  this is guaranteed to be always false.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Note that `main` is required to have the return type `int`. Anything else is at best not portable.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Not exactly, i've seen cases with gcc when i could call a member function even if the pointer pointing to the object was a nullpointer

Comment: Does `right = NULL = left;` compiles?

Comment: @Lorand That's undefined behavior, meaning behaving as-if `this` wasn't `nullptr` would still be conformant. In other words, assuming `this` is never `nullptr` is a correct assumption.

Comment: @Lorand try again with modern gcc, it will optimize it away.

Comment: Yes, it does compile

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I tried with gcc 5. But in any case i agree that the null  check wasn't what op actually intended on doing

Comment: `this` is only a pointer for backward compatibility reasons - if references existed already when `this` was specified, it would have gotten one for sure...

Comment: gcc 7 will remove it, clang will remove it. Calling a method through a null pointer is UB, as Francois indicated.

Comment: `right = NULL = left;` - must be some strange definition of `NULL` then, if this really compiles. But with modern C++, you should prefer language *keywords* (`nullptr`) over outdated (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`) anyway...

Comment: @shirleysven The problem is that `right = NULL = left;` is assigning `left` (an unitialized variable) to `right` and `NULL` (somehow). It shouldn't compile. And if it does, I have no idea what it is actually doing (even if `left` was initialized).

Comment: Thanks, I understand about `nullptr`

Comment: But still didn't understand what causes this error.

Comment: This code is riddled with undefined behaviors. Delete everything and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, you're passing `this`, which is a `Tree<T>* const`, to `insertion`, which expects a `Node<T>*`.

You probably meant `root = insertion(root, value);`.

(There are countless other problems with that code, but this is the source of that particular error message.)